# How to get the current state in SPA (react hooks)?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I created a blog (Single page application). I can see each post in a single page. I clicked edit for update the content. When I jump to the edit page, how can I get the current state of singlePost in the edit page? Can I transfer the state as props in different pages? Thanks!

**singlePostPage.js**

```
const { id } = useParams();
  const [singlePost, setSinglePost] = useState(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    getSinglePost(id).then((data) => setSinglePost(data[0]));
  }, [id, singlePost]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => setSinglePost(null);
  }, []);

  const handleDeletePost = () => {
    deletePost(id).then(() => history.push("/"));
  };

  const handleEditPost = () => {
    history.push(`/editPost/${id}`);
  };

  return (
    <PostPageContainer>
      {singlePost && <h1>{singlePost.title}</h1>}
      {singlePost && <h4>{timeConverter(singlePost.createdAt)}</h4>}
      <PostContent>{singlePost && singlePost.body}</PostContent>
      {singlePost && <button onClick={handleEditPost}>Edit</button>}
      {singlePost && <button onClick={handleDeletePost}>Delete</button>}
    </PostPageContainer>
  );
```

**editPostPage.js**

```
const { id } = useParams();
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState();

  const history = useHistory();

  const handlePostSubmit = () => {
    updatePost({ title, content, id }).then((res) => {
      if (res.ok === 0) {
        return setErrorMessage(res.message);
      }
      history.push("/");
    });
  };

  const handleTitleChange = (e) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleContentChange = (e) => {
    setContent(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <PostFormContainer>
      <PostForm onSubmit={handlePostSubmit}>
        <TitleInput type="text" onChange={handleTitleChange} value={title} />
        <ContentInput
          onChange={handleContentChange}
          value={content}
          rows="10"
        />
        <SubmitBtn>Submit</SubmitBtn>
      </PostForm>
    </PostFormContainer>
  );
```

Comment: I'd recommend that you do this with a custom hook and the context api. The custom hook provides the state (kind of globally) and will be made available via context.
Of course you could also use full state management lib like Redux, which I wouldn't recommend though because your use case seems a bit smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the approach you followed here, there are few ways to achieve what you expect.

Since you are using routing to navigate to edit page, you can pass the values from state using query params from routing. (Which is not ideal, as the blog post can contain long strings)

The best way to handle this case is to use State Management Library(Redux) or React Context API.

So you will have to manage your state globally and extract the required details from global state to the page.